# Show current date and time in <canvas> using JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to make a few shapes using the `<canvas>` tag in HTML 5 and then add a current date and time text using the same tag. All this has to be done using javascript. I can display time and date normally in JS but have no idea how to add it to my canvas.

```
function doFirst()
{
var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas = x.getContext('2d');

canvas.arc(200,200,150,0,2*Math.PI);
canvas.stroke();

today = new Date(); 
document.write("<br />The time now is: ",today.getHours(),":",today.getMinutes()); 
document.write("<br />The date is: ", today.getDate(),"/",today.getMonth()+1,"/",today.getYear());
 }

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

So thats what i currently have, my drawing wont show if i use that new date function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not clear your question. please explain

Comment: i want to show current date and time using javascript in my <canvas> tag. How can i do that? @NitishKumar

Comment: @NitishKumar Question is perfectly clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.write` writes to the document... which is closed by the time `window.onload` fires and therefore your entire page is nuked.

Try [`canvas.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas) instead, for drawing text to the canvas.

As an aside, the variable name `canvas` is misleading. Typically `ctx` is used to refer to the context.

Comment: if i do canvas.fillText("<br />The time now is: ",today.getHours(),":",today.getMinutes()); that, woudnt the browser get confused with commas as they are usually for x,y axis?

Comment: Well yes, but you should use `+` for string concatenation. Also, you can't do HTML.